# How can I create metaball-like shape merging (like Figma's Union feature) in SVG/CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

In my layout there is such [a figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BE8UZm.png), which is made by combining two rectangles with a rounded radius. I could make it a cdu picture, but besides that there are cards that are also made up. Can you tell me how to make cards in CSS?

[image]
[image]

P.S. I tried to do this with :before, but I couldn't make rounded corners. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7Kygm.png)

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to take the tour and read this.

Comment: The effect on the left side of your screenshot is a metaball-like effect (as the "goo"'s shape is a function of the two square's distance), but the effect on the right-side is completely different (as the "goo" appears to be manually placed and not based on any function of the content or boxes' locations relative to each other).